# Question: how to use and with where in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, backend

when I want to get data from a database in native PHP I use queries but in laravel, you don't write queries you use their model and their functions to get the data for example:

```
ex::where('name','test')->get();
```

in native PHP:

```
select * from ex where name='test'
```

and my issue is I don't know how to use and like this query:

```
select * from ex where name='test' and id='5'
```

I searched and looked thru the documentation but no answer was found.

Comment: `ex::where('name', 'test')->where('id', 5)->get();`

Comment: "I searched and looked thru the documentation but no answer was found." ...  10 seconds of looking:   https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses .

Comment: plus laravel documentation is the most easy to read out there. you can become an expert just by the documentation

Comment: @N69S he can't find this basic functionality in the docs, he's not looking. simple as that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put another where, its really simple just put it like this

```
ex::where('name', 'test')->where('id', 5)->get();
//or if you want directly the instance and not a collection
ex::where('name', 'test')->find(5);
```

If you want to use the OR operator you can also do something like this

```
ex::where('name', 'test')->orWhere('id', 5)->get();
```

More [in documentations](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: thank you very much you saved me a ton of time, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

There is no 'AND' with where in Laravel Eloquent.
You have to write another 'where' with the required condition.

Another way is: run queries using the DB facade. The DB facade provides methods for each type of query: select, update, insert, delete, and statement.

Ex. DB::statement("UPDATE teachers SET price = ".$price." where id=".$id." AND status='A'");

Do not forget to use DB

Comment: That is a very bad practice to encourage. Your example is sensitive to sql injection and really hard to maintain.

Comment: Excuse me ? There is a `AND`. why would you suggest the DB facade when he's using Eloquent. Please remove this answer. Why would you even write your own queries in Laravel